# How does the Array in Swift know whether it contains an element?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift

The Array in Swift is able to store any Swift type which including Struct, Enum and Class instance. But there is no function `==` be able to compare any type of Swift object. And the `===` operator is also only able to compare two references. So I wonder, when the function `contains()` get called, how the Array in Swift knows it contains an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the function signature:

```
func contains<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Equatable>(seq: S, x: S.Generator.Element) -> Bool
```

you see that the element in the array must me of a type implementing the `Equatable` protocol, which contains one method only:

```
func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

So any type implementing the `Equatable` protocol can be used.

If you define your own class (or struct etc.), to use `contains` you just have to implement that protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've known nothing about the where clause until saw your answer.